# how to many to one with mybatis annotation

Tags: mybatis

I hope you will understand what I'm looking for in ***myBatis annotation***

The table A return me many values. The table B return me one value for each values of the table A.

And I would like to store all the values from the table B in a list.

I can do it by making to query. One from the table A, get the list, and make a "if" with the query for table B and store the result in a list.

But I'm try to see if I can do something like this:

```
@Select(SELECT id FROM table_A WHERE a_value = #{aValue})
@Results({
    @Result(property = "images", javaType = List.class, column="id",
            one= @One(select = "findOneValueInTableB"))})
list<String> fingManyThingsInTableA(string aValue);


@Select(SELECT value FROM table_B WHERE id_table_A = #{id})
String findOnValueInTableB(int id);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and give me the following error:

*"nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2"*

***Edited to show tables and the result I'm expecting***

[image]

***Expected result:***

```
[value1, value2, value3, value 4]
```

Thanks for your help and your suggestions.

Comment: What language do you use? It is not Java ?? `list<String value> fingManyThingsInTableA(something);`. It seems to me that, you get more results than could be stored in one String. `String value findOnValueInTableB(id_from_tableA);`.

Comment: I use JAVA, but what I wrote for the code is to explain.

Comment: Let me writing to it in a more correct way

Comment: As you get a well defined error, you should have code that caused this error. Why don't you show that code? The code above makes no sense for a Java program-

Comment: I wrote the error but I don't know how to color it in red to make it clear. And the code I wrote should work :)

Comment: This is still no valid Java code (beside you have declared your own string (not String) and list ( not List) class. But let's assume that are typos. Your second select tries to find a single (@One) value entry of type String in the tableB. The recordset is identified by the id. If for instance there are more than one entries in hte tableB with the same id you get more resulting record sets. And that's what the error says. I don't know the organisation of your database. Pg e.g. allows to use list types for fields. So perhaps you have unique ids but a List of String instead a single String.

Comment: Well I understand the error message. I know that the table A return me more that 1 value so, as I wrote the code it can't work. I'm trying to know if I can write a code, that looks like this, instead of making 1 query and getting the list, then with the list from the table A making an other query to the table B the get the value. Is it making more sens for you ?

Comment: Sorry @PeterPaulKiefer this code is writing in myBatis annotation. There is nothing related in JAVA. :)

Comment: The string and list type names are part of the Java Method declaration, not the part of the annotations. The tableA can provide you more than 1 result, that's no problem as you have a List of Strings as result. But tableB seems to return a List of someting and that the problem as you have only one String to store the result. And your relation is of type @One but it seems you get more results from the select.

Comment: Yes I agree and I know this :) . The writing, in the `result`, `one = @ One` or `many = @Many` is not the correct writing because the table A return many values and the table B return only 1 value for each value return by the table A

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer is trying to tell you `list<String> fingManyThingsInTableA(string aValue);` should be written as `List<String> fingManyThingsInTableA(String aValue);` (inaccurate sample code wastes everyone's time). Anyway, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Try adding 1) concrete data (rows in those tables), 2) the parameter value(s) and 3) the expected result (some assertion lines should be sufficient).

Comment: Sorry @ave it's a bad writing from me, and I think people can understand it.  for a list instead of List and string instead of String  :)

Comment: @ave I've added, as you asked a simple design of the 2 tables and the result I'm expected as a `List<String>`  Thanks you very much for your help

Comment: Someone from a forum answer me that it's a SelectList I need to do, but it doesn't know how to do in annotation. Instead of I can do it in sql by a nested select query. He say it's better and faster.

Comment: @JBD It's better! So, simply put, you need only one column of `table_b` ? Then, you should probably consider writing a query with JOIN e.g. `select table_b.a_value from table_a inner join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.id_table_A`. Or a query with nested select as _someone_ suggested.

Comment: @ave you are right !  I did it with a SubQuery or Inner Query.  My question was only to know if it was possible to do the same with only myBatis writing. It looks it's not possible.

Comment: @jbd With MyBatis, there is SQL first. And you use MyBatis to map that SQL to Java objects. :)